# How to sort these data in R

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
data<-read.table (text=" ID Name    Surname colour  A1  A2  A3  Income1 M1  M2  M3  Income2 P1  P2  P3  Income3 Y1  Y2  Y3  Inccome4    R1  R2  R3  Income5 B1  B2  B3  Income6
656 Nim Kami    blue    12  20  18  A   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
656 Nim Kami    yellow  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  16  19  18  B   NA  NA  NA  NA  9   1   2   Q   NA  NA  NA  NA
656 Nim Kami    red NA  NA  NA  NA  12  14  11  M   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
656 Nim Kami    black   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  15  16  18  G   NA  NA  NA  NA  12  12  12  Q
444 Liz Zor dark    10  10  10  Q   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
444 Liz Zor purple  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  14  11  18  M   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
444 Liz Zor gray    NA  NA  NA  NA  20  20  20  D   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  11  11  11  G   NA  NA  NA  NA
444 Liz Zor green   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  13  11  10  R   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  19  11  6   Z

", header=TRUE)
```

and  the outcome would be :

```
OUTCOME<-read.table (text="ID   Name    Surname colour1 A1  A2  A3  Income1 colour2 M1  M2  M3  Income2 colour3 P1  P2  P3  Income3 colour4 Y1  Y2  Y3  Income4 colour5 R1  R2  R3  Income5 colour6 B1  B2  B3  Income6
656 Nim Kami    blue    12  20  18  A   red 12  14  11  M   yellow  16  19  18  B   black   15  16  18  G   yellow  9   1   2   Q   black   12  12  12  Q
444 Liz Zor dark    10  10  10  Q   gray    20  20  20  D   green   13  11  10  R   purple  14  11  18  M   gray    11  11  11  G   green   19  11  6   Z
", header=TRUE)
```

I want to remove duplicates and then create colour 1 to colour 6.

Comment: Your original data looks like the result from a bad pivot. I recommend going back to the method/routine that creates `data` and fix the problem there. For example, `pivot_wider` allows to create multiple "grouped" columns which is probably what you're after. I don't recommend doing post-hoc kludges.

Comment: I understand your point, but there is no problem with the original data and method

Comment: All the `NA`s seem to have originated from a poor pivot. If you fix this there is no need for a kludgy fix to remove "duplicates" (which are not really duplicates) and create new columns (with in-between old column positions).

Comment: Not really, there is nothing to fix, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution, based on `purrr::map_dfr`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  group_split(ID) %>% 
  map_dfr(
    ~ data.frame(
      ID = .x$ID[1],
      Name = .x$Name[1],
      Surname = .x$Surname[1],
      Color1 = .x$colour[!is.na(.x$A1)],
      A1 = .x$A1[!is.na(.x$A1)],
      A2 = .x$A2[!is.na(.x$A2)],
      A3 = .x$A3[!is.na(.x$A3)],
      Income1 = .x$Income1[!is.na(.x$Income1)],
      Color2 = .x$colour[!is.na(.x$M1)],
      M1 = .x$M1[!is.na(.x$M1)],
      M2 = .x$M2[!is.na(.x$M2)],
      M3 = .x$M3[!is.na(.x$M3)],
      Income2 = .x$Income2[!is.na(.x$Income2)],
      Color3 = .x$colour[!is.na(.x$P1)],
      P1 = .x$P1[!is.na(.x$P1)],
      P2 = .x$P2[!is.na(.x$P2)],
      P3 = .x$P3[!is.na(.x$P3)],
      Income3 = .x$Income3[!is.na(.x$Income3)],
      Color4 = .x$colour[!is.na(.x$Y1)],
      Y1 = .x$Y1[!is.na(.x$Y1)],
      Y2 = .x$Y2[!is.na(.x$Y2)],
      Y3 = .x$Y3[!is.na(.x$Y3)],
      Income4 = .x$Inccome4[!is.na(.x$Inccome4)],
      Color5 = .x$colour[!is.na(.x$R1)],
      R1 = .x$R1[!is.na(.x$R1)],
      R2 = .x$R2[!is.na(.x$R2)],
      R3 = .x$R3[!is.na(.x$R3)],
      Income5 = .x$Income5[!is.na(.x$Income5)],
      Color6 = .x$colour[!is.na(.x$B1)],
      B1 = .x$B1[!is.na(.x$B1)],
      B2 = .x$B2[!is.na(.x$B2)],
      B3 = .x$B3[!is.na(.x$B3)],
      Income6 = .x$Income6[!is.na(.x$Income6)]
    )
  )

#>    ID Name Surname Color1 A1 A2 A3 Income1 Color2 M1 M2 M3 Income2 Color3 P1 P2
#> 1 444  Liz     Zor   dark 10 10 10       Q   gray 20 20 20       D  green 13 11
#> 2 656  Nim    Kami   blue 12 20 18       A    red 12 14 11       M yellow 16 19
#>   P3 Income3 Color4 Y1 Y2 Y3 Income4 Color5 R1 R2 R3 Income5 Color6 B1 B2 B3
#> 1 10       R purple 14 11 18       M   gray 11 11 11       G  green 19 11  6
#> 2 18       B  black 15 16 18       G yellow  9  1  2       Q  black 12 12 12
#>   Income6
#> 1       Z
#> 2       Q
```